# Substitute a local value in the global expression inside a function

Tags: python, function, variable-assignment

I want to substitute some parameters inside the function
(i) without creating additional parameters of the function f(parameters),
(ii) without changing variables globally.
The problem is that one variable is defined outside the function and I would like to keep it this way (z can be potentially a result of many other preceding cells).

```
import sympy
x_hh=sympy.Symbol("x_hh") 
z=x_hh+2;

def v():
    x_hh=2;
    a=1;
    utility = a*z
    return utility
display(v())
```

As the output I have `x_hh+2`, but I want to have `4`.

Comment: you want to change `z`inside `v`?

Comment: We need more information to help you. Which variable do you want to change?  in which case? why can't you add parameters to the function? can't you just `z=someehitngNew` in the function?

Comment: Hi, thank you for your answer. I want to temporarily substitute the local value of x_hh inside z and then get substituted z as the output of the function. Meanwhile, the global value of z shouldn't change.

Answer (score 0):

Your code will be interpreted from up to down.
So `z=x_hh+2;` will only be called once at the beginning.

you could simply create a new variable inside the funciton:

```
import sympy
x_hh=sympy.Symbol("x_hh") 
z=x_hh+2

def v():
    x_hh=2; #the value of x_hh was changed here
    new_var = x_hh+2 # this variable will be up-to-date and won't affect z
    a=1;
    utility = a*new_var #we use the new variable instead of z
    return utility
display(v())
```

Comment: Yes, I understand that. But z can be a very complex expression, which can consist of other function, other cells. I would not like to recreate it inside the function, but simply use local values as part of the parameters when calling z inside the function.

Comment: I don't know if it's helpful, but this method works fine in wolfram mathematica:
```
z=x+2;
f[y_]:=Block[{a,x},
a=1;x=2;
a*z
]
```